# How to accurately make configure script use the updated gcc version on CentOS?

Tags: gcc, centos7, glibc

I have followed instructions provided in other articles to fix the below issue but still doesn't appear to work for my system. I am trying to upgrade glibc to v2.27 on my CentOS 7.3 machine. I downloaded the package and running into the below compiler dependency during the configure script execution:

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.27
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
...
...
checking if gcc is sufficient to build libc... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for python3... no
checking for python... python
configure: error: 
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: compiler
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

So I upgraded my gcc and verified the upgraded version:
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.2.0

I also have the following environment variable set in my bashrc:
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc

For some reason, the configure script still throws the same error based on which it appears that the upgraded gcc version isn't being used.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you *explicitly* ask for correct GCC: `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.27 CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc` ?

Comment: That worked, many thanks!